# buffer Array to String and then saving in directory

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, buffer, bufferedimage

I am new to React and I am currently facing an issue that I have API written in Express.js in which I am receiving ur fetching whatever it is called an image uploaded from mobile device in a buffer Array and now I have to convert it into string and add extension to it (let say .jpg) and store it into MongoDB Atlas here is my API written in Express ```module.exports.submitFormDataFile = async (req, res) => {

```
var hkeyArray = [];
    const body = req.body;
    const collection_name = body.form_collect_name;

    const formstructureresult = await FormsStructure.findOne({
        collection_name: collection_name
    });

    formstructureresult.formdata.forEach((eachData) => {
        if (eachData.element === 'file') hkeyArray.push(eachData.hkey);
    });

    //  console.log(hkeyArray)

    hkeyArray.forEach((element) => {
        //In this part I was supposed to convert it in string and save with extension 
        console.log(req.files[element].data);
    });

    if (body._id != '' && body._id != null) {
        try {

            const result = db.collection(
                collection_name
            );

            const results = await result.findOne({
                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(body._id)
            });

            if (!results) {
                res.status(200).json({
                    ERROR: 1,
                    MESSAGE: 'Invalid Record'
                });
            } else {
                delete body._id;
                var newvalues = { $set: body};
                const resu = await result.updateOne(results, newvalues);
                if (!resu) {
                    res.status(404).json({
                        ERROR: '1',
                        MESSAGE: 'Unable to update'
                    });
                } else {
                    res.status(200).json({
                        SUCCESS: '1',
                        MESSAGE: 'Record Updated Successfully'
                    });
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error, 'error');
        }
    }
};
```

As everything is dynamic so I am fetching *hkey* which are the name in MongoDB from a **collection** and fetching other collection based on **req.body** received and byteArray is also received from **req.body** and conversion of it into a string I have to update document as shown in the code

Answer (score 0):

Probleum solved! In my case solution was simple I just changed the code accordingly

```
hkeyArray.forEach((element) => {
        //In this part I was supposed to convert it in string and save with extension 
        var imagedata = req.files[element].data;
        let buff = new Buffer.from(imagedata , 'base64');
        fs.writeFile(`element+'.jpg'`,buff, function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('Saved!');
          });
          body[element] = element+'.jpg'
    });
```